How can i implement Repository designing pattern for mern project
How can I implement the repository design pattern in a MERN stack project? Also, how should I configure the database ,logic's to follow the repository pattern?
what is the abstraction layer in repository pattern
I am new to this concept, so I would appreciate a detailed explanation. Thanks in advance!

The repository pattern is the abstraction. I’d probably suggest searching the web for “repository pattern” or similar first.
